# How to override a class in django.contrib.admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I don't want to modify the source code of Django directly, since any updates will remove my modifications.

So, how to override the `ChangeList` class in `django.contrib.admin.views.main`, and tell django to use it instead of the original one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, I have not tested it but I did something similar in the past in Python. You can take advantage of the fact that python does not reimport things if they are already loaded.

At the start of yoru app (before any django imports), e.g., in your __init__.py file:

1. Import the class

```py
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
```

2. Next define define your own somewhere

```py
class CustomChangeList:
   pass
```

3. Assign the new class to the import ChangeList

```py
ChangeList = CustomChangeList
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I couldn't get it overridden..